# Passar parâmetros(incluindo uma imagem) para PHP com Axios utilizando formData

Tags: javascript, react, axios, formdata

Criei um componente React para ser meu botão personalizado de input:

```
getFormData(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var imagefile = document.querySelector('#btn_file_logo');
    formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);
    return formData;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="logo_input" onClick={() => this.abirInputFile()}><i className="fa fa-upload"> </i> {this.props.texto}</div>
            <input type="file" className="form-control-file" id="btn_file_logo" name="btn_file_logo"  />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Porem estou com dificuldade para utilizar o `formData`. A função `getFormData()` deve retornar o `formData` para outro componente, que vai pega-lo e adicionar com `append` o restante dos parâmetros que serão enviados ao servidor(utilizo PHP com o Slim Framework no server-side):

```
cadastrar(){
    this.refs.load.openLoad();

    var formData = this.refs.input_logo.getFormData();
    formData.append('nome',this.state.nome);
    formData.append('cnpj',this.state.cnpj);

    axios.post(config.urlBase + 'adicionar_empresa', {empresa:formData}).then(res => {
      if(res.data.status){
        this.refs.sucesso.openSucesso(2000);
        this.refs.load.closeLoad();
        this.limparCampos();
      }else{
        this.refs.erro.openErro(3000);
        this.refs.load.closeLoad();
      }
    })
}
```

O problema é que no servidor chegam vazios os parâmetros.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver

```
axios.post(config.urlBase + 'adicionar_empresa', {empresa:formData})
```

estava passando o parâmetro em JSON, o correto é assim

```
axios.post(config.urlBase + 'adicionar_empresa', formData)
```